# SpringBoot NullPointerException: null

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Spring Boot me tira el siguiente error y no tengo idea porque
la tabla creada dentro de PhpMyAdmin (fichamedica) no tiene primary key

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at com.packagepractico.ejerciciospring.MainController.getAllUsers(MainController.java:27) ~[classes/:na]

Esta es mi Entidad "fichamedica"

```
package com.packagepractico.ejerciciospring;


@Entity
@Table(name = "fichamedica")
public class FichaMedica {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    
    private String nom_Emp;
    private String estado_Civil;
    private String fuma_Sino;
    private String diabetes_Sino;
    private String asma_Sino;
    private String cirugias_Sino;
    private String quemaduras_Sino;
    private String medicamentos_Sino;

    //CON SUS GETTERS Y SETTERS CORRESPONDIENTES
      
}
```

El repositorio de fichamedica:

```
package com.packagepractico.ejerciciospring;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;


public interface FichaMedicaRepository extends CrudRepository <FichaMedica, Integer> {
    
}
```

y el controlador:

```
package com.packagepractico.ejerciciospring;


@Controller
@RequestMapping("")
public class MainController {
    @Autowired
    
    //private CargosEmpleadosRepository cargosempleadosRepository;
    private EmpleadosRepository empleadosRepository;
    private FichaMedicaRepository fichamedicaRepository;
    
    @GetMapping("/all")
    public @ResponseBody Iterable<FichaMedica> getAllUsers(){
        return fichamedicaRepository.findAll();
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Favor de leer Cómo formular una buena pregunta

Comment: Te falta marcar la interface `FichaMedicaRepository` con la anotación `@Repository`. Como no la tienes marcada, spring no crea el bean y de ahí que obtengas el NPE. Por otro lado, dices que la llave primaria de `FichaMedica` es `Integer` cuando declaras `extends CrudRepository <FichaMedica, Integer>`, pero veo que lo que marcas como llave primaria `nom_Emp` es un String. No veo consistencia en tu código. ¿Es `nom_Emp` un  entero o un string?